# Don't show block until after a number of comments

Tags: blocks, comments

I have created a block and I don't want it to display until there are a number of comments posted on the node because if I just display the block the site will look ugly.

How would I go on to make it that when the node has lets say 6 comments the block or some content will show but when the node has less than 6 comments the block wont show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use php code for your block "Show block on specific pages" fieldset settings, paste next code:

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  if ($node) {
    return $node->comment_count > 5;
  }
}
return FALSE;
?>
```

p.s. Enable PHP filter module, if you not see PHP code option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making the block using Views, you should be able to do this pretty easily by adding a view filter of "Content: Comment Count" is greater than or equal to "6"

It will then only show the block when it has results that meet your criteria.